# confirm box more than one time appears

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using ajax using jquery, I am deleting a row using the following code snippet:

```
$('#example a.delete'). live('click', function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this row?"))
{

     alert("Hello World!")
}

});
```

When I click **grid view show button**, grid view appears without page refreshing due to ajax. If I click **grid view show button** more than one time, it refresh again grid view area, accordingly. But confirm box show more than one time,which is equal to my no. of clicks on **grid-view show button**, when I click on a single row delete button.

How can avoid this !

**Edited**

HTML CODE:

```
<td><a class="delete" href="#" style="margin-left: 10px"><img src="images/delete-icon.png" width="16px" height="16px" /></a></td>
```

**Edited**

Complete Code Snippet:

```
$('#example a.delete'). live('click', function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this row?"))
{
    $getCode = $(this).parent().parent().attr('id');
    var oTable = $('#example').dataTable();
    var index =oTable.fnGetPosition( document.getElementById($getCode) );

    $.post("DeleteDepartment", {
        depID:$getCode                   
    }, function(data) {
        if(data.result >0){
            var oTable = $('#example').dataTable();
            oTable.fnDeleteRow( index );
        }else{
            alert("Operation Fail");
        }
    });

}

});
```

Comment: what jquery version are you using?

Comment: jQuery v1.7.1 @ltiong_sh

Answer (score 5):

```
$('#example a.delete').unbind('click').bind('click', function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();

     if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this row?"))
     {

        alert("Hello World!")
     }
```

});

Comment: your code is not working for dynamically new row added, until page refresh @pankil thakkar

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be attaching multiple events to the button. Are you sure you're only calling `live()` ONCE, and once only? If you call it multiple times, you get multiple handlers.

(Of course, this is why I prefer to just use `.onclick = function() {...}` personally)

Comment: Yes Dear,I am calling it once @Kolink

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the code is written to do the confirm once for each click.
If you want it to confirm only once you have to make the code remember that you already confirmed.

The row is not deleted until the server calls your success callback function. During that time you can keep clicking on the row and firing the click event.

You could set a variable or a property on the row when the user confirms and then check this variable each time they click. Only show the confirm message if the variable is not set.

Or you could change the state of the element you click, change its image, change style, set an attribute. You could both inform your code that it has been clicked and indicate to the user that the row is already marked for deletion.

Or you could try jquery's .one() method to attach the event.

Comment: alert("Hello World!") is just sample , here I am removing the current row. but it confirm more than one time @joshp

Comment: I see. That was not apparent from the code. If you don't find a solution, probably best to make a small example that actually shows the problem and put it in jsfiddle.

Comment: Ok, that explains it. The delete happens after the .post returns from the server. That's why you can click it twice.

Comment: @BothFM The post is an async call, so you release control and allow UI actions. Then the browser calls back your success function that deletes the row.

Comment: one thing dear, I am not clicking twice. on one single click, confirm box appears two or more times , one by one. when I cancel on the first confirm box, second suddenly appears.

Comment: @josho yes! The post is an async call, so you release control and allow UI actions. Then the browser calls back your success function that deletes the row. Please example!

Comment: @Both. If you get two responses from one click then the people who answered that you are probably attaching multiple event handlers to the click sound like they are on the right track.

Comment: dear, this issue can be resolved by replacing **live** function by **click** function. but it create one problem more that is , dynamically added new row not does not work until refresh. means the row that I have added dynamically , when i clilc on delete button of this  new row, nothing happened, until refresh